# How would I make my background image move with the cursor? Trying to implement this codepen

Tags: javascript, css

So I'm trying to get this exact effect: http://codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/rEDIC

I can't get it to work in my code.

This is my css and the bit I want this effect applied to:

```
#header {

margin: -8px 0 0 0;
background-image:url(img/header_bg.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
position:relative;
background-size: cover;
```

}

```
<div id="header"> </div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var movementStrength = 25;
var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
$("#header").mousemove(function(e){
          var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
          var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
          var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
          var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
          $('#header').css("background-position", newvalueX+"px     "+newvalueY+"px");
});
});
```

My css is different to the person's codepen css - which is probably why it's not working, however when I change it, it screws up the background (it disappears). Any help would be much appreciated - I'm not very knowledgeable on js.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** NEVER MIND: FIXED IT. I moved the  to the end of the  - just above the  tag - instead of having it up the top.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3ugny0r/1/) I just set the width and the height of the image in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

adding `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` will get it working. `position:relative` cannot calculate the `height` as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you forgot to set the width and height of your image in the CSS:

```
#header {
    margin: -8px 0 0 0;
    background-image:url(http://www.brandwatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/570x320xtrolls.jpg.pagespeed.ic.-hEjJryY-x.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    position:relative;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 570px;
    width: 320px;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/q3ugny0r/1/)

Comment: #header {
 
 margin: -8px 0 0 0;
 background-image:url(img/header_bg.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 position:relative;
 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
 height:20%;
  
}

Okay added the height and width (tried using px as well) and it's still not working. Can't figure it out - because as you showed it's working fine on yours. Could it be because this isn't the only thing on my web page?

Comment: Google chrome error is saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ".

Comment: NEVER MIND: FIXED IT. I moved the <script> to the end of the <head> - just above the </head> tag - instead of having it up the top.

Comment: @Celine Then please, consider accepting my answer if it was of any help.